# Dynmamically Created Images With JavaScript Not Propery Loading

Tags: javascript, dom

currently practicing with APIs and working on a project to do a mock up of the Pexels website. Having an issue with the creation of images, but not quite sure why these will not load.

```
let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      let photoURL = response.photos.map(function (photo) {
        return photo.url;
      });

      console.log(photoURL);

      const imagesContainer = document.querySelector('.images-container');
      imagesContainer.innerHTML = ``;
      photoURL.forEach(photo => {
        const imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        imageDiv.classList.add('image-div');
        imageDiv.innerHTML = `
          <img class="created-image" src=${photo}>
        `;
        imagesContainer.appendChild(imageDiv);
      });
```

photoURL is an array of all the image URLs, simply trying to run a forEach on it to attach the src and append to the imagesContainer. Everything seems to be working/appending as planned, but the images will not load. If I look in the chrome dev console, the images will even have the src attribute with links that if I copy paste, do indeed work in the browser.

Comment: The above code works fine in my tests so it looks like the issue lies elsewhere. Unfortunately, we don't have a lot to go on. I would suggest inspecting the image styles (are the display: none, are the width and height correct etc)

Comment: Currently getting an error in the console that says "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html", is this likely just an API issue? Repeats 15 times, once for each image produced.

Currently for the image styling I was just starting with base placeholders of the image divs taking up 33% of their overall container and each image was set to be 100% of each div. Display none isn't active or anything....things are being created and appended (that icon you get for an unfound image is showing up) but not the actual image itself

Comment: Do you have an example of `photo.url` for one of them?

Comment: Sure!

"https://www.pexels.com/photo/selective-focus-close-up-photo-of-brown-wilson-pigskin-football-on-green-grass-2570139/" 

This is the first value of the photoURL array if I search for Football. So then I ran a forEach and am trying to directly assign this value to the src of photo parameter

Comment: The url you have is returning HTML, not an image

Comment: As @epascarello mentioned, those URLs are to HTML pages, not the actual images, which is why the browser is not displaying them in the `img` tag.

Comment: Sigh....so obvious in retrospect man. Alright, so it's the map method that I need to adjust then to actually grab the proper attribute